# Is there a module for Python that recieves (reads) text from a picture?

Tags: python, image, module, ocr

In relation to my question: If not for Python, what other programming languages have/acquire this feature?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition?

Comment: @ZiyaoWei Yes, a module that performs along those lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the [`python-tesseract`](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract) module, which wraps the [`tesseract`](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) OCR system.